# OpenVPN on AWS: Unexpected error: invalid_profile: Unable to find a server-locked or autologin profile for this user

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I have setup a OpenVPN server using an AMI from AWS Marketplace. and setup with the default options.

Now I am trying to connect to that vpn server but getting this error:

> "Unexpected error: invalid_profile: Unable to find a server-locked or
>   autologin profile for this user"

I am not sure what is the error. anybody faced this issue with OpenVPN before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out that Mac OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) was the culprit. Apple has introduced SIP (System Integration Protection) in 10.11 which was causing this issue and I was not able to connect with OpenVPN

here is the forum topic : https://forums.openvpn.net/topic19879.html

and to disable SIP on 10.11 : http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/